# How do I connect to an older sql database using LocalDb in VS 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express, localdb

I am trying to construct a connection string to a 2008 SQL Express database file in VS 2012. I am getting an error dialog:

> This database file is not compatible with the current instance of SQL
>   Server. To resolve this issue, you must upgrade the database file by
>   creating a new data connection, or you must modify the existing
>   connection to this database file. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235986

I followed the link to Microsoft's always wonderfully helpful documentation (cough, cough..). When I went through the upgrade database function, I was not presented with a prompt to upgrade the file. I was really hoping to use LocalDb instead of having to do a install of SQL Express 2008.  Any thoughts?

**OTHER:** Why hasn't Visual Studio implemented clicking on links in the error dialogs after all these years? Is it really hard to implement?

Comment: I totally agree with you about not having a clickable link in the error dialog. It's frustrating, really! C'mon Microsoft... One has to type that link in the browser window. OMG.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From my experience of a few instants ago:

1. Forget about trying to open the old `SQL Server Express` `.mdf` file in Visual Studio 2012. During the conversion process of an old VS 2010 solution to VS 2012 it tells you can do that by just double clicking the database file and upgrade it to use LocalDb instead. That's a complete lie! :D
2. Open [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), select the `Databases` node, right click it and select `Attach...`.
3. Provide the path for the `.mdf` file, click OK and then you should be good to go.
4. Now inside `Visual Studio 2012`, open `Server Explorer` (menu `View -> Server Explorer`), right click `Data Connections` and then select `Add Connection...`. In `Server name:` put `(localdb)\v11.0` and in `Connect to a database:` select the database you attached previously.
5. Right click the `Data Connection` just added in `Solution Explorer` and select `Properties`. Copy the `Connection String` property and replace the `Web.Config` or `App.Config` one with this value.

**Note:** In `SQL Server Management Studio` I got an error while trying to attach an old `.mdf` file I got from this sample project from DayPilot: [Scheduler for ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor (C#, VB.NET, SQL Server)](http://code.daypilot.org/62492/scheduler-for-asp-net-mvc-4-razor). It was related to a path issue regarding the `.log` file that accompanies the `.mdf` database file. I just selected the `.log` file entry in the `Attach...` dialog window and removed it. Then tried to attach the database again and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me. I up-voted before even trying it when I read "That's a complete lie!". So true.

Comment: This works also for Visual Studio 2013, for those wondering. Thank you!

Comment: this is what I got when i went to download center. "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Answer (score 53):

my simple way:

1. go to **VisualStadio 2012**
2. In **Server Explorer** Windows
3. open **Data Connections**
4. Right click on **ASPNETDB.MDF**
5. click on **Modify Connection...**
6. a new windows open for you ... you just click **OK**
7. if other windows open for you click **Yes**
8. FINISH ( be Happy ) :D

Comment: You´re awesome buddy, many thanks! However, when I choose Tables-> Add New Table, nothing happens, do you know why?

Comment: I'm happy! Thank you!

Comment: @Omid Finish (be Happy) :D - yes very happy indeed, thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON 
    ( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\<database name>.mdf' ),
    ( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\<database name>.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

As described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165673%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

go to VisualStadio 2012
In Server Explorer Windows
open Data Connections
Right click on ASPNETDB.MDF
click on Modify Connection...
a new windows open for you ... you just click OK
if other windows open for you click Yes

Answer (score 0):

open sql server management studio
connect localDB
remove deattach same name  mdf file
then attach your mdf file

go to visual studio
in server explorer-> dataconnection
right click on your database ->  modify connection -> text connection -> click OK